# Cloudflare showing html code instead of web page on Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, frontend, cloudflare

I have an Angular 4 app , that i deployed it using docker on aws ec2 machine. I'm using CloudFlare to manage my DNS.

The problem is on Chrome when i try to refresh the page, instead of showing me the web page , it returns me the html code of the index.If i access the page directly via the IPV4 from the machine the app works fine.

On Firefox/Safari everything works as expecting.

This is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PageName</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Serif|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/menu/favicon.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="global_root">
            <app-root></app-root>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

These are the response headers from IPV4 :

```
Connection: keep-alive 
Date: Fri, 04 Jan 2019 14:25:56 GMT 
Server: nginx/1.15.7 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: Express
```

These are the response headers via cloudflare:

```
cf-ray: 493e5f00093f9706-FRA 
date: Fri, 04 Jan 2019 14:24:51 GMT 
expect-ct: max-age=604800, 
report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct" 
server: cloudflare 
status: 200 
strict-transport-security: max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains 
x-content-type-options: nosniff 
x-powered-by: Express
```

Comment: What are the HTTP response headers direct vs cloudflare?

Comment: The response headers directly  : `Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 04 Jan 2019 14:25:56 GMT
Server: nginx/1.15.7
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: Express`

Comment: Response headers via cloudflare : `cf-ray: 493e5f00093f9706-FRA
date: Fri, 04 Jan 2019 14:24:51 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-powered-by: Express`

Comment: How are you serving this document? I'm not familiar with the angular cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you’re not setting the `Content-Type` header, and Cloudflare is helpfully adding `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` to all responses, and Chrome applies this to documents while Firefox and Safari don't apply it to documents (only to stylesheets and scripts).

Express sets `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` by default, so there could be something weird — how exactly are you serving this document? You could try `res.type("html")` to be explicit.

Comment: Yeah , removing the nosniff solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that you may run into character encoding issues if you don't properly set the content type. The default is Latin-1, but you're probably using UTF-8, so if you use anything outside of ASCII there will be an issue. You should fix this eventually.